# Healtcheck for all servers in a domain

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have two servers located 1 in eu aws zone and one in us aws zone.

I've configured route53 to return address for the eu server if user ip comes from europe and return the ip for the us server if client is from north america.

Obviously the associated domain is always the same that is www.testserver.com

I'm now implementing a monitoring system ( no i cannot use aws functionality ) that calls every minute a page on this domain called statusCheck, but as there's no problem to call that page in the eu server ( i'm from italy so route53 redirects me in the eu server ) i cannot reach the page in the us server.

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do one of the following:

- Configure your health checks to go directly against the IP addresses of the servers instead of the domain name.
- Configure extra domain names in Route53 for each server, like us.example.com->us-ip-address and eu.example.com->eu-ip-address. Then configure your health checks to use those domain names.

Comment: I'm following the second way at the moment, because on that site there's more than one virtual host and going by ip makes the default virtualhost reply. Thanks